# Store user entry from entry field, tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I've seen other questions on a similar topic to this, I've struggled to make sense of them so I'm asking this one.

I have this program, the majority of the code is below, It's a basic GUI.

I'm having problems with the entry fields that take the users first name and surname, the block of code associated with this is here:

```
tk.Label(self, text='First Name: ').pack(side=TOP)
EntryFieldFN = Entry(self)
EntryFieldFN.pack(pady=2, padx=2)

tk.Label(self, text='Surname: ').pack()
EntryFieldSN = Entry(self)
EntryFieldSN.pack(pady=2, padx=2)

FirstName = EntryFieldFN.get()
Surname = EntryFieldSN.get()
```

I've been unable to work out how to store the user input from these fields into variables that I can then use later. I wish to use the first name and surname of the user in the FinalWindow() function, which I want to act as a receipt of purchase for the order.

```
def FinalWindow():
    win = Toplevel()
    LabelRW = Label(win, text='Receipt of Purchase')
    ExitProg = Button(win, text='Exit', command=sys.exit)
    LabelRW.pack()
    ExitProg.pack()
    win.title('Virtual Receipt')

class Till(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master=master, **kw)
        self.price_string = tk.StringVar()
        tk.Label(self, text='GUI Program - Till System').pack(side=TOP)
        tk.Label(self, text='First Name: ').pack(side=TOP)

        EntryFieldFN = Entry(self)
        EntryFieldFN.pack(pady=2, padx=2)

        tk.Label(self, text='Surname: ').pack()
        EntryFieldSN = Entry(self)
        EntryFieldSN.pack(pady=2, padx=2)

        FirstName = EntryFieldFN.get()
        Surname = EntryFieldSN.get()

        tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.price_string).pack(side=BOTTOM)
        tk.Label(self, text="Total Price: ").pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.items = []

    # For each stock item, create an IntVar, a checkbox and keep record of the price/name

        for idx, item in enumerate(stock_items):
            new_item = {}
            new_item['var'] = tk.IntVar()
            new_item['check'] = tk.Checkbutton(self, text=item['name'], variable=new_item['var'], command=self.recalculate)
            new_item['check'].pack()
            new_item['name'] = item['name']
            new_item['price'] = item['price']
            self.items.append(new_item)

        ExitButton = Button(root, text='Exit', command=sys.exit)
        OrderButton = Button(root, text='Order', command=FinalWindow)
        ExitButton.pack(side=BOTTOM, padx=2, pady=2)
        OrderButton.pack(side=BOTTOM, padx=2, pady=2)
        ExitButton.config(height=1, width=8)
        OrderButton.config(height=1, width=8)

# Recalculate is called when ever a checkbox is checked/unchecked

    def recalculate(self):
        total_price = 0

    # Go through each item and if it is selected add its price to the total

        for item in self.items:
            if item['var'].get():
                total_price += item['price']

    # Display out total price

        self.price_string.set('£ {:.2f}'.format(total_price))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    Till(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

I've tried a couple of things so far, none of which have worked, I don't know if it would be a good idea to use global variables for the inputs.

Comment: you forget to post `stock_items`

Comment: You could use `command=lambda: FinalWindow(EntryFieldFN.get(), EntryFieldSN.get(), self.price_string.get())` in your button to get the data to the `FinalWindow` function. Also, please use `root.destroy` to quit the program, not `sys.exit`. Also also please decide on whether you do or don't want to wildcard import Tkinter, you call Tkinter classes both with and without the `tk.` prefix now which is messy.

Comment: Okay I will try this, hope it works out fine, just for future knowledge, what's the difference between using root.destroy and sys.exit?

Comment: `sys.exit` exits the python program while the tkinter mainloop is still running. `root.destroy` stops the tkinter mainloop and then continues executing the python script that's behind the `root.mainloop()` call. Usually this is the last line in your script so it exits nicely.

Comment: Okay, well I can change that over, I added in your suggestion for the button, if it was the OrderButton you were talking about, It now gives the error when clicked on 'FinalWindow() takes 0 posistional arguments, but 3 were given'

Comment: Well yeah, if you do that you also need to change the `FinalWindow` function to accept the arguments and do something with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two ways to solve this problem. Both of them start by having your button call a method which is part of the class:

```
OrderButton = Button(root, text='Order', command=self.do_order)
```

You also need to make sure that you keep a reference to the entry widgets, so instead of `EntryFieldFN` and `EntryFieldSN` you should use `self.EntryFieldFN` and `self.EntryFieldSN`. This is so that you can get access to the widgets from anywhere in the class.

```
def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
    ...
    self.EntryFieldFN = Entry(self)
    self.EntryFieldSN = Entry(self)
    ...
```

Note: this concept applies to all other input widgets (eg: the Checkbuttons). I'm limiting the answer to these two widgets to make the code examples smaller and easier to manage.

With that out of the way, you can do one of two things: your function can get the values and pass it to `FinalWindow`, or it can pass itself to `FinalWindow` and let `FinalWindow` get the values it needs.

### Passing the individual values

For the first case, you need to define `FinalWindow` to take the values as parameters:

```
def FinalWindow(first, last):
    ...
```

Next, have `do_order` get the values and call the function:

```
def do_order(self):
    first_name = self.EntryFieldFN.get()
    surname = self.EntryFieldSN.get()
    window = FinalWindow(first_name, surname)
```

### Passing the class instance

Instead of passing the values, you can pass the instance of `Till` to `FinalWindow`.

First, modify FinalWindow to accept a single parameter, which is a instance of `Till`. It can then use this instance to get the data it needs.

```
def FinalWindow(till):
    first_name = till.EntryFieldFN.get()
    surname = till.EntryFieldSN.get()
    ...
```

Next, modify `do_order` to simply pass itself to the function:

```
def do_order(self):
    window = FinalWindow(self)
```